# How to build and debug a c++ executable using Bazel on windows 10 x64

Tags: c++, mingw, bazel

I want to debug a c++ code using the generated executable with bazel, but for some reason, the bazel don't build the code on x64 architecture or the executable does not work on debug mode.

My files are

### main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int a = 3;
    int b = 5;
    int c = a + b;

    /* code */
    std::cout << "Hello world" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I use this command to build my app

> bazel build //src/app:main --strip=never --compilation_mode=dbg

but when I try to debug the app after I set breakpoints I get this error in the console

for example, if I run

> `gdb main.exe`

then

> (gdb) break main

I get

> No symbol table is loaded.

Question how to load the symbols inside the main.exe when I build the code using the **bazel build**  command??

Comment: I only see a warning and presumably `x86_64` is your architecture, so it shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: @user10605163 check this question, I explain in details 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53821315/how-to-debug-a-bazel-build-using-c-on-windows-10-and-vscode

Comment: Yes in that question you are getting an error message, but in this question I don't see any error message. Which one is it?

Answer (score 5):

Bazel on Windows builds C++ code using MSVC by default. I reckon the debugging data format used by GCC is different from MSVC's .pdb files, which would explain why you can't use `gdb` to debug the Bazel-built binary.

To build with MingW GCC instead of the default MSVC, you must tell Bazel to use that compiler:

```
bazel build -c dbg --compiler=mingw-gcc //src/app:main
```

Here's more info about this `--compiler` flag value [1].

This failed for me first, so I followed instructions of https://stackoverflow.com/a/30071634/7778502 and installed `mingw-w64-x86_64-gcc`.

Now I could build `//src/app:main` with Bazel, and use `gdb` to set a breakpoint:

```
$ gdb /c/src/so53840959/CPP_TESTS/project/bazel-bin/main/app.exe
GNU gdb (GDB) 7.11.1
...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 3, in <module>
ImportError: No module named libstdcxx.v6.printers
/etc/gdbinit:6: Error in sourced command file:
Error while executing Python code.
Reading symbols from /c/src/so53840959/CPP_TESTS/project/bazel-bin/main/app.exe...done.
(gdb) break main
Breakpoint 1 at 0x401568
(gdb)
```

I'm not familiar with `gdb` but the Error looks benign and everything looks OK.

---

[1] To find this `--compiler` flag value, I looked at the registered C++ toolchains. I'm not aware of a user-friendly way to do this (and I don't want to go into details about toolchains here) but all we need to know is this:

1. Run `bazel query @local_config_cc//:toolchain --output=build`.

   This will print the C++ toolchains rule's definition, which is an auto-generated build rule that tells Bazel what C++ toolchains it can use.
2. Look at the line starting with `toolchains = {...`.

   It is a dictionary where each key defines a `--cpu` flag value, or a `--cpu` and `--compiler` flag value pair. Without going into details about syntax here, you can probably see an entry with key `x64_windows|mingw-gcc`, meaning you can build with `--cpu=x64_windows` and `--compiler=mingw-gcc`. (Since `--cpu=x64_windows` is the default on Windows, you can leave it out.)